# Continuous integration - sensitive files and dependencies on build agents

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, teamcity, credentials

I would like to set up multiple CI tasks that perform the following tasks:

1. Check out project source from VCS (triggered by code changes)
2. Download sensitive configuration files (not checked into VCS)
3. Build project
4. Deploy project

I am using TeamCity specifically, but I think the same concepts apply elsewhere. I set up a CI server and multiple build agents (as Docker containers on the same server or possibly scattered across other machines). My understanding is that these build agents are all minimally configured the same way and can build any project at any time.

My problem is how to handle sensitive files. Many of my builds require property files that hold sensitive information/credentials and are not checked into VCS. I was thinking of having some global repository (i.e. AWS S3) where I can encrypt sensitive files and have the build agents download them when needed. However, *this would require that all build agents have AWS CLI software installed on them so that they can download those files.*

**How can I pass files with sensitive information to distributed build agents?**

If I move ahead with the global depository, then I need to install AWS CLI on the build agents. While my question is specifically about AWS CLI, I can imagine other projects that would require other software to be installed before building. **How do I set up build agent environments so that they can build multiple projects with different dependencies?**

Do I set up *all* build agents with *all* software required to build *all* projects? Like a common Docker image or something? This seems like a bad idea as it places build configuration in different places (TeamCity server and a separate Dockerfile). It also may lead to a monolithic, common Docker image.

Or do I create a build step (per project) that downloads and installs the software required *for one project*? This seems like a better idea, but then I'm installing software (like the AWS CLI) every time I build. Regardless if that build agent already has the software installed. I also need to worry about software from multiple projects clashing. Do I have to then add a cleanup step that removes the software? Or should I look into making a Docker container for building each project?

Is there another approach? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, you should really narrow this down to one question. If you have multiple questions then make them multiple questions. Next, I've voted to close this as "Primarily opinion based" because there are multiple ways to answer all these questions and the answers will be different for everyone. Instead of "Is it good practice to store sensitive files on build agents" you might ask "How can I distribute sensitive information to build agents securely". The latter has possible ways of answering that could be useful to future persons looking to do something similar.

Comment: Thanks @AndyShinn, I tried to make it sound a bit less opinion based. While I understand your comment regarding multiple questions, I feel that these questions are tightly coupled enough that separating into two SO questions would lose context and make the answer less useful. Either way, appreciate the feedback!